# Linux pictures browser that hilights those with an EXIF location

Tags: linux, file-management, gps, image-viewer, exif

I want a Linux program that fits these requirements:

- ✅ Shows differently pictures that contain GPS latitude/longitude in their EXIF.
- ✅ Thumbnail-centric: Shows a thumbnail of each picture in a folder. It can be a file browser, but most of the screen space must be occupied by the miniature images rather than text.
- ✅ Supports drag-and-drop to modern web browsers
- ✅ Fast
- ✅ Open source

It could look like this (I am open to other designs):

[image: File browser with GPS overlay]

My final goal is to easily find good pictures (while preferring those that contain location data) and upload them with the mouse.

([*related question for Android*](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/51639/android-file-explorer-with-programmable-icon-overlays-ex-show-globe-if-picture))

Answer (score 2):

**2018 UPDATE: The other answer is better!**

Far from perfect, but [Nautilus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Files) can do something like that with an extension:

[image]

- ✅ Shows differently pictures that contain GPS latitude/longitude in their EXIF. Problem: The presence of GPS information is textual, which is difficult to notice, making my workflow less efficient.
- ❌ Not thumbnail-centric: Only one column, which means a lot of space wasted, and impossible to see many pictures on the screen. The most prominent is the filename (which is irrelevant) rather than the miniature.
  Only one column, which means a lot of space wasted, and impossible to see many pictures on the screen. Also, thumbnails can not be made bigger than that.
- ✅ Supports drag-and-drop to modern web browsers
- ❌ Not very fast
- ✅ Open source

Installation: Follow the instructions in sections 1 and 2 at http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/76-gnome/349-gnome-nautilus-exif-iptc-xmp-gps-column-property-extension

Answer (score 0):

I developed an extension for Nautilus that overlays a "+" if GPS coordinates are present in the picture's EXIF:

[image]

https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/nautilus-exif-coordinates-or-not

Advantages:

- ✅ Shows a big green cross-shaped overlay icon on files that have an EXIF location. I should really make a better icon than this, though. Also, when applying the overlay the thumbnail becomes smaller, not sure why.
- ✅ Thumbnail-centric: Yes thumbnails take most of the space, you can easily set their size.
- ✅ Supports drag-and-drop to modern web browsers
- ❌ Quite slow, 1 second per 10 pictures
- ✅ Open source

Compatible with Nautilus, Nemo, Caja