# Android file explorer with programmable icon overlays (ex: show globe if picture has EXIF coordinates)

Tags: android, gallery

Icon overlays can be used to quickly show that a file has a particular property:

[image]

A file can have several overlays, for instead a lock and a green checkbox, in such case the overlays might be dispersed on several corners of the thumbnails so that all are visible.

I need a file explorer that shows:

1. A particular overlay (for instance a small Earth globe) when a picture has EXIF geographical coordinates.
2. A particular overlay (for instance a puzzle piece) when a picture has already been uploaded to http://commons.wikimedia.org

I realize that the second criteria is a requirement that nobody except me has, so I welcome solutions that allow me to develop my own icon overlays, for instance by coding them in Java or another language. My code must be able to call a web service (there is a fast API to check that criteria from the image's checksum).

Also, the file explorer must show thumbnails of pictures. Actually, it can be a gallery rather than a file explorer, as I will only use the software to browse my pictures.

(*[kind-of-related question for Linux](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/48685/linux-pictures-browser-that-hilights-those-with-an-exif-location)*)